# How to mock an API request with a regex URL?

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, httpcalloutmock

What I want to achieve is set a response for an URL that matches a regex pattern.

I took this code from the [Apex documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm).

```
    @isTest
    global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
        global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
            System.assertEquals('http://api.salesforce.com/foo/bar', req.getEndpoint());
            System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());

            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.setBody('{"foo":"bar"}');
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }
```

How could I mock the request for a dynamic url, for example : `http://api.salesforce.com/foo/bar?token=xxx`?

My main programming language is Ruby, and I can achieve this by using code similar to:

```
stub_request(:get, %r{http:\/\/api.salesforce.com\/foo\/bar\/(.)*})
```

**Update:** Could you please explain why you're down-voting me? I think it's an accurate question regarding a feature that is easily achievable in all programming languages I've used.

Comment: Why do you really care what the endpoint is? That's just asserting on platform behavior. The docs don't always set the best example.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I have seen on testing mock callouts (sfdcfox). You set what should be returned at the time you make the call. Since you really do not care about the endpoint because you know what you are hitting at that point, you just want to get the response you are testing.: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141330/help-on-invokable-apex-test-class-and-future-callout-apex-test-class/141334#141334

Comment: The endpoint is quite complicated, it is formed of several arguments that get generated. I assumed it's quite easy to just use a regex. This will not be used to test a unit, but rather a feature.

Comment: @Vasile - Then I am confused as to what you are asking as the MockImpl you used as an example can only be used from test methods. It may be able to be used for some purpose called directly from code I guess but it cannot be implemented to provide an actual response to a callout. (And just fyi I did not do the down vote so this is not in response to that)

Comment: What I'm basically trying to achieve is to test a feature that calls a few methods in my class. That class makes few requests to external services, and I want to mock the responses. I should receive identical responses. The called URLs are going to be different, because they contain some timestamps and tokens.

Comment: @Vasile - How do you define "Test" since your comments say that this will not be part of the `@isTest` framework.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to create an `HttpCalloutMock` implementation that can be used to mock the correct response to different callout requests, based upon the URL?  This is possible to do, using Regular Expressions, although it may not be the correct way to test.

In Apex, the `Test.setMock()` method allows you to specify a single class to be used to mock another class, effective until the end of the current test method, or until `setMock()` is called again.  It's really only documented for use with REST and SOAP callouts and the internals are not explained anywhere I've seen, but the signature indicates it takes a type (`System.Type`) and an `Object`, and it appears from usage that the `Object` must be of the same type (or implement a common interface) as the first parameter.  What I **believe** is happening (conjecture warning) is that when your code tries to make an HTTP callout from a Test context, the system checks to see if there's a mock implementation registered for the system class `HttpCalloutMock`, and if so, it uses that class (regardless of the URL) to get a mocked response (and if not, it throws an exception, as callouts aren't allowed from test context).  Likewise if making a SOAP callout, the system checks to see if there's a mock implementation registered for the system class `WebServiceMock`.

So in outline, here's how you could do what you are asking:

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        String URL = req.getEndpoint();
        // Use regex to pull info from URL
        String token= ...;

        if (token == 'foo') {
          //passing request obj incase other info is needed to construct response
          return FooResponse(req); 
        }
        else if (token == 'bar') {
          return BarResponse(req);
        }
        else {
          assert(false, 'UNEXPECTED TOKEN: ' + token);
        }
    }

    private FooResponse(HttpRequest req)
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"baz":"foo"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }

    private FooBarResponse(HttpRequest req)
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"baz":"bar"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }

}
```

I glossed over the mechanics of using Regular Expressions, but [Apex RegEx support is based on the Java Pattern/Matcher model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm).  However, you don't really need a regex here, you just need to get the value of an URL param.  You can get a map (think Ruby `Hash`) of the [request params directly using req.params()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm#apex_System_RestRequest_params);

That said, I'm still not sure if that's the correct way to do this.  If you are writing a unit test for a (non-test) method that may call one of several endpoints depending on context, then yes, this makes sense.  If you are writing multiple tests, where each tests a method that always calls a single endpoint, consider using a separate `HttpCalloutMock` implementation for each test (or each endpoint).  You can write your mock implementations as [inner classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm?search_text=inner%20class) within your test classes to reduce clutter of your Apex namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I'm not sure there's a place for the conditionals in my code, as the token can have many values, that's why I wanted to use a regex. But your approach makes sense.