# Help with test class for Batch Apex

Tags: apex, batch

Below is my callout class which makes two different callouts to external system. In callout 1, it gets a token. In Callout 2, it uses that token to retrieve the actual data. For some reason, I`m not getting a complete test coverage on this class.

After line " deserializeResults3 = (accountParser)System.JSON.deserialize(fieldValue, accountParser.class);", nothing is being covered.

```
global class CalloutsAccounts1 implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts{
   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String query =  'SELECT Id FROM Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){
        HttpRequest obj = new HttpRequest(); 
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        String reqBody = '{ "user": "sales_user", "password": "sales_password" }';
        obj.setMethod('POST');
        obj.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        obj.setEndPoint('https://test.samplepoint.com/api/UserSrvs.svc/Login');
        obj.setBody(reqBody);
        obj.getheader('Auth-Token');
        res = http.send(obj);
                                system.debug('Oauth Response: '+res.getbody());
                               system.debug('Header Auth-Token Response: '+res.getHeader('Auth-Token'));

                authtoken objAuthenticationInfo = (authtoken)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(), authtoken.class);
                System.debug('objAuthenticationInfo: '+objAuthenticationInfo);


                                String token = res.getHeader('Auth-Token');
                                system.debug('token: '+token);    


        Http h1 = new Http();
        HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
        String reqBody2 = '{"Accountype" : "workforce"}'; 
        req1.setHeader('Auth-Token', token);
        req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req1.setMethod('POST');
         req1.setBody(reqBody2);

        req1.setEndpoint('https://test.samplepoint.com/api/accservices.svc/accountfeed');
        system.debug('======req1========'+req1);
        HttpResponse res1 = h1.send(req1);
        system.debug('==========res1============'+res1.getBody());



                   JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res1.getBody());
                    parser.nextToken();
                     parser.nextValue();
                            system.debug('==========parser============'+parser);

                    String fieldName = parser.getCurrentName();
                    String fieldValue = parser.getText(); 
        system.debug('==========fieldValue============'+fieldValue);
    accountParser deserializeResults3 =  new accountParser();
    deserializeResults3 = (accountParser)System.JSON.deserialize(fieldValue, accountParser.class);

     List <accountParser.cls_account> advisorList = new List<accountParser.cls_account>();
    advisorList = deserializeResults3.root.accounts.account;

           Map <Decimal,Id> AdvisorMap = New Map  <Decimal,Id>   ();

        List <Account> advisorAccList = [SELECT Id, Fact_Finder_Client_ID__c, RecordTypeID FROM Account WHERE RecordTypeid = '012410000009tw6[![enter image description here][1]][1]'];

        For (Account Acs : advisorAccList) {
            If (Acs.Fact_Finder_Client_ID__c != null)
            AdvisorMap.put(Acs.Fact_Finder_Client_ID__c, Acs.ID);
            system.debug('@@@'+AdvisorMap);
                }
             Map <String,Id> HouseholdMap = New Map  <String,Id>   ();

        List <Account> advisorAccList1 = [SELECT Id, SSN__c, RecordTypeID FROM Account WHERE RecordTypeid = '012410000009Yr4'];

        For (Account Acs1 : advisorAccList1) {
            If (Acs1.SSN__c != null)
            HouseholdMap.put(Acs1.SSN__c, Acs1.ID);
                }

List<Financial_Account__c> lstAccount = new List<Financial_Account__c>();
for(accountParser.cls_account cand : advisorList){
    Financial_Account__c PFA = New Financial_Account__c();
    //PFA.Cirrus_Unique_ID__c =  cand.account_id;

    //Map Advisor Lookup
   PFA._Advisor_ID__c = cand.advisor_id; 
   PFA.Advisor__c = AdvisorMap.get(PFA._Advisor_ID__c );  

    //Map Household Client Lookup
    PFA._Household_ID2__c = cand.household_id;
   if (HouseholdMap.get(PFA._Household_ID2__c) == null) {
       PFA.Client__c = '0013C000003wagf'; 
} else if (PFA._Household_ID2__c != null) {
         PFA.Client__c = HouseholdMap.get(PFA._Household_ID2__c);  
}


    PFA._Unique_ID__c =  cand.account_id;
    PFA.Financial_Account_Number__c =  cand.account_num;
    PFA.Account_Type__c =  cand.account_type;
    PFA.Tax_Status__c=  cand.taxable_flg;
    PFA.Investment_Objective__c =  cand.objective;
    if (cand.inception_date != null) {
    PFA.Account_Opening__c = date.parse(cand.inception_date);
        }
        if (cand.perf_begin_date != null) {
    PFA._perf_begin_date__c = date.parse(cand.perf_begin_date);
        }
     }
    PFA.Account_Type__c =  cand.account_type;
    PFA.compute_flg__c = cand.compute_flg;
    PFA.Account_Description__c = cand.description;
    PFA.fwc_hh_id__c = cand.fwc_hh_id;


    lstAccount.add(PFA);
}


Boolean isUpsertfirstTime = true;
try {
    upsert lstAccount Financial_Account_Number__c;
}catch (DMLException e) {
                System.debug('Re-trying');
                if(isUpsertfirstTime){
                        upsert lstAccount Financial_Account_Number__c;
                                isUpsertfirstTime = false;
              }
}


   }       

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
              CalloutsAccounts2 myContactBatch = new CalloutsAccounts2();
      Id batchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(myContactBatch);

   }
```

Mock:

```
    @isTest
global class Example1_HttpCalloutMocktes implements HttpCalloutMock {

    //  Implement this interface method
    global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {

        //  Prepare a response to return
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        //  Can use the HttpRequest details to shape the response
        if (req.getMethod() == 'POST' && req.getEndpoint() == 'https://test.samplepoint.com/api/UserSrvs.svc/Login') { 

            //  Provide a response for this endpoint
        res.setBody('{"User":{"indenty":250751503,"GroupID":0,"IdentityProviderID":0,"IdentityProviderUserID":"test","FirstName":"test","LastName":"Services","Email":"test@test.com","AffiliateId":111,"Type":14,"SubType":1,"Gender":"M","InUseFlg":false},"AffiliatePreferences":null}');
     res.setHeader('Auth-Token', '6VIitOCHBJfSA7lZIlgdNLpxw+v5AvcksXlVjtnjg34qwLYHwDTHlFZYj2xC7X0nTU6djaWruJa03+FgN8cet3kwuu4N5HaAhEbldu5t8+gDH9siTt/wO58O+6872sG8=');
        res.setStatusCode(200);                  
        }


          if (req.getMethod() == 'POST' && req.getEndpoint() == 'https://test.samplepoint.com/api/accservices.svc/accountfeed') { 
                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            //  Provide a response for this endpoint
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.setBody('{  "d": "{\"root\":{\"pagination\":{\"accounts\":{\"pages\":\"111\"},\"page\":\"1\",\"pageSize\":\"2\"},\"accounts\":{\"account\":[{\"account_id\":\"512\",\"account_num\":\"35111516\",\"account_type\":\" Remainder Trust\",\"taxable_flg\":\"1\",\"compute \":\"0\",\"description\":\"ZZ-test, dave B\",\"add_id\":\"57\",\"fwc_id\":\"test-test\",\" begin_date\":\"07/10/2003\",\"inc_date\":\"07/09/2003\",\"termination_date\":\"02/24/2014\",\"last_date\":\"04/30/2008\",\"test_id\":\"18\",\"planning_id\":\"1175\",\"account_num\":\"20696291\",\"objective\":\"WCM \"},{\"account_id\":\"513\",\"account_num\":\"1515661\",\"account_type\":\"Individual Account\",\"taxable_flg\":\"1\",\" compute\":\"0\",\"description\":\"ZZ-tst, dave B\",\"add_id\":\"57\",\"fwc _id\":\"NWCP - test\",\" begin_date\":\"06/30/2003\",\" inc_date\":\"07/09/2006\",\"termination_date\":\"02/24/2014\",\"last_date\":\"04/30/2008\",\"test_id\":\"18\",\"planning_id\":\"175\",\" account_num\":\"1251515\",\"objective\":\"test\"}]}}}"}');
     res.setHeader('Auth-Token', '6VIitOCHBJfSA7lZIlgdNLpxw+v5AvcksXlVjtnjg34qwLYHwDTHlFZYj2xC7X0nTU6djaWruJa03+FgN8cet3kwuu4N5HaAhEbldu5t8+gDH9siTt/wO58O+6872sG8=');
        res.setStatusCode(200);              
        }


        return res;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
 @isTest
private class CalloutClassTest {
     @isTest static void testCallout() {
      Test.startTest();
       Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
       CalloutsAccounts1 CA= new CalloutsAccounts1 ();
       Account acc = new Account( Name = 'My Test Account' );
       Insert acc;
        Database.executeBatch(new CalloutsAccounts1 (), 100);
       Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

SS[image]

Comment: One of the best ways to mock callouts i have seen here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141330/help-on-invokable-apex-test-class-and-future-callout-apex-test-class - sfdcfox's answer

Comment: Thank you SFDCFox. This increased my code coverage. Though it is only giving me a coverage till line 46 now. Anything after line 46 (which is     "deserializeResults3 = (accParser)System.JSON.deserialize(fieldValue, accParser.class); ")  is not being covered, how can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure you are setting the response to a valid JSON response so it can parse it

Comment: Review my first comment and implement that. Currently your code will never return `HttpResponse res1` as you have a return statement above that and that part of the code is not reachable. With your current code you need to check the request endpoint and return the appropriate response. If you implement what I linked to in my first answer you can define what is returned within the test itself

Comment: Thank you Eric, issue is that I`m new to Apex. If its not too much to ask, could you please give me an example how I can do that?

Comment: Step 1 - Follow the link in my first comment, review, digest, implement. Step 2 Visit: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts - The information you need has already been provided. If you get stuck on a SPECIFIC spot then we can help you get past it.

Comment: Thank you Eric, appreciate your help. I`m now trying to return response based on endpoint however still getting the same error. I have edited above questions with updated Mock response. Could you please take a look at the code and let me know whr I`m going wrong? Appreciate your help ...  Tom

Comment: You could not have modified it and tested it as you have posted in your question as your mock class will not compile in its current state. Just pasting code and asking for someone to fix it when you could not have possibly tested or debugged it yourself will not get many answers here. We are here to help you not do it for you.

Comment: Hi Eric, intention is not to waste your time. Like I said, Im new to Apex and still figuring out how the language works. I have updated my Mock class again. If possible, pls let me know when I`m going wrong.

Comment: Ok so this seems to no longer be about a Mock Callout issue it seems like an issue with your JSON string. What is the error that you are getting? Have to attempted to use that string and deserialize in the Dev console. Debug it there and see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you Eric, you were right. I was passing incorrect JSON format in the Mock. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Remember the process you went through for this. It is a useful process when debugging any issue you come across. Breaking down the pieces, focusing on the issue, then testing the elements of that issue to find the breaking point. Added an answer so you can close this out.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the discussion has been in comments but in summary:

1. Currently your code will never return HttpResponse res1 as you have a return statement above that and that part of the code is not reachable.

With your current code you need to check the request endpoint and return the appropriate response.

2. Check the value of the JSON string you are using against your deserialization