# HttpCalloutMock that returns a null response

Tags: httprequest, httpcalloutmock

I have a simple class that send an `HTTPRequest` and gets an `HTTPResponse`.

I wanted to create a NullResponseMock that implements HttpCalloutMock and returns null, but I get an exception as:

> System.UnexpectedException: Script-thrown exception.

Based on the code below, could you please point me in the right direction?

The class that sends the request

```
public class HTTPUtility {

public static string EMPTY_RESPONSE = 'EMPTY_RESPONSE';
public static string NON_SUCCESS_CODE = 'NON_SUCCESS_CODE';
public static integer SUCCESS_CODE = 200;

public static string callRestService(String endpoint, String message, String httpMethod, integer timeout, string auth) {
    System.debug('>>>>> endpoint: ' + endpoint);
    System.debug('>>>>> message: ' + message);
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    //Set HTTPRequest Method
    req.setMethod(httpMethod);
    //Set HTTPRequest header properties
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('Caller-System', 'SALESFORCE');
    if (!string.isEmpty(auth)) {
        req.setHeader('Authorization', auth);
    }
    if (message != null)
        req.setBody(message);
    if (timeout > 0) {
        req.setTimeout(timeout);
    }

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = null;
    res = http.send(req);

    if (res == null) {
        throw new HTTPException(EMPTY_RESPONSE, 'An error occured during the callout. The response was empty!');
    }
    if (res.getStatusCode() != SUCCESS_CODE) {
        throw new HTTPException(NON_SUCCESS_CODE, 'An error occured during the callout. An error code was returned!', res);
    }
    System.debug('Response: ' + res.toString());
    System.debug('Response body:' + res.getBody());
    return res.getBody();
}
```

The mock

```
@isTest
public class NullResponseMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
protected Integer code;
protected String status;
protected String bodyAsString;
protected Blob bodyAsBlob;
protected Map<String, String> responseHeaders;

public NullResponseMock(Integer code, String status, String body, Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {
    this.code = code;
    this.status = status;
    this.bodyAsString = body;
    this.bodyAsBlob = null;
    this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;
}

public NullResponseMock(Integer code, String status, Blob body, Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {
    this.code = code;
    this.status = status;
    this.bodyAsBlob = body;
    this.bodyAsString = null;
    this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;
}

public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();
    resp.setStatusCode(code);
    resp.setStatus(status);
    if (bodyAsBlob != null) {
        resp.setBodyAsBlob(bodyAsBlob);
    } else {
        if (bodyAsString != null) {
            resp.setBody(bodyAsString);
        }
    }

    if (responseHeaders != null) {
        for (String key : responseHeaders.keySet()) {
            resp.setHeader(key, responseHeaders.get(key));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

The test that fails

```
tatic testMethod void testCallRestServiceReturnsErrorCodeWhenResponseIsNull() {
        String internalCode;
        NullResponseMock unlockCustomerAccountMock = new NullResponseMock(400, 'NOK', '', null);
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, unlockCustomerAccountMock);
        try {
            Test.startTest();
            HTTPUtility.callRestService('http://localhost', 'OK', 'POST', -1, null);
            Test.stopTest();

        } catch (HTTPException e) {
            System.debug('>>>>> Test result: ' + e.getMessage());
            internalCode = e.getInternalCode();
        }
        System.assertEquals(HTTPUtility.EMPTY_RESPONSE, internalCode);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Irina, Welcome to Stackexchange. To get better support, please update your question with appropriate code and details on what you have tried.

Comment: @Irina Clington, and do take some time to visit [ask] and take the [tour]. welcome to SFSE!

Comment: @IrinaClington - Do yourself a favor and implement your HTTPMocks using the following pattern: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141330/help-on-invokable-apex-test-class-and-future-callout-apex-test-class/141334#141334 - much easier to control what is returned at the test method level.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Eric, I have a similar constructor on my main HTTPmock  "public SingleRequestMock(Integer code, String status, String body, Map<String, String> responseHeaders)" and I've added the one you mentioned as well "public SingleRequestMock(HttpResponse r)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your implementation of the `respond` method. The respond method *must* return an `HTTPResponse` and you're currently returning `null`.

```
public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();

    /* snip */

    return null; // must return a non-null HttpResponse
}
```

Why would you not receive back an HTTP 500 or similar error status code to indicate that the remote server encountered a problem? What's the business use case you're testing?

Are you instead looking to mock the behavior when the remote server returns no payload?

Comment: No, I'm not testing the body,  and really I can't think of why the method would return null, but I'd call it defensive programming to add an if not null. So I wanted to test that case. Should I just assume http.send(req) will never return null and skip both the if and the test?

Comment: Yes, in my opinion, if the platform makes an `HTTPRequest` you should assume it will also provide you a response to that request. From an alternative perspective, you shouldn't need to unit test whether the platform does the right thing, you'll get a response.