# http request in a for loop

Tags: apex, batch, httprequest

I need to do a callout to Google Analytics in Salesforce. Based on the documentation, I can't bulkify the request with the records involved, because I can only have one date range.

Is doing a http request in a for loop problematic? I would do this loop in a batch.

```
for(Account a : accounts) {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(requestBody);

    HTTPResponse res;
    if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGAData());
        res = new Http().send(req);
    } else {
        res = new Http().send(req);
    }

    if(res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        // parse response
    } else {
        // throw error 
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no problem with this code as written, but I suggest you set the mock in your unit test method, not the class itself. As written, you won't be able to get 100% coverage.

Make sure you save any DML operations until all your calls are done, which you should do anyways, because DML in a loop is a bad idea.

Comment: How do you set the mock in a unit test when you are making a callout from within a batch? Do you just set the mock before calling the batch?

Comment: @TylerZika call Test.setMock after the Test.startTest, then queue your batchable call, then use Test.stopTest to execute the batch.

Comment: What if multiple callouts happen in one batch? I do one callout to get a current access token, and the other to get the desired data. The reason my code is like that is I do make multiple callouts in my batch, and was able to achieve close to 100% code coverage, but I agree it's bad practice to put test code in the actual class.

Comment: @TylerZika you can use the EchoHttpMock design that I use, as shown in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/141330/2984

Comment: @sfdcfox does this mean: call out inside loops are safe and they don't make my code hit any limits?

Comment: @Bahman.A There is a limit of 100 calls per transaction and 120 seconds of total callout time. However, calling in a loop is indeed possible as long as you follow the rules.

Comment: @sfdcfox I appreciate your quick response! This helps a lot thank you!!